# zoom not working for scale values below 1 in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, zooming

For zoom in d3,graph vanishes if scale value goes below 1.

I have given scaleExtent[1,10] then zooming is smooth , i want to zoom out much more so i gave scaleExtent[0.5,10] ,when scale value goes below 1 in second case the graph vanishes.

```
zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.5,10]).on("zoom", function(){      
                svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");       
        });
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using for the zoom?

Comment: Hi Lars, I have added  code , please check

Comment: Looks like it should work. Can you post a complete reproducible example please, preferably on jsfiddle or something like that?